# JQuery: slidedown sub menu on hover of link and slideup only if the user doesnt navigate to the submenu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an effect where if the user hovers over a link and only the link (as apposed to the whole list item)within the main menu bar then the sub-menu slides down. The problem is that when I set the callback function to slide up `onmouseout` the sub-menu slides up so the user doesn't even have a chance to move their mouse over it. NOTE: I must use `padding` on the list items for whatever reason o using `margins` instead is not an option. also you'll notice that if you hover over any part of the list item even if its not a link the sub-menu will drop down. Thanks In advance!

Below is a link to an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/a4qbn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/LMWLn/4/

Two things: I changed the jQuery selector for your Hover() call to only match the top-level menu LI elements.  Your previous one was matching both the top-level LI elements as well as all of the LI elements in the child menu.  Nothing good would come from that.

Second, I added a delay on mouseleave before hiding the menu.  This gives the user time to move the mouse from the parent menu and into the child menu.  If the user gets there within 100ms, then the hide is canceled.

Edit: Here's a new version that only activates when you put the mouse on the links: http://jsfiddle.net/LMWLn/9/

Notice on this version, the menu activates when the mouse enters the link.  But it only *deactivates* when the mouse leaves the entire LI.  This avoids the unseemly flash when you leisurely move the mouse down from the link to the submenu.

Comment: Thanks this is way better than what I wrote, however the sub menu still slides down when I hover anywhere over the list item I'm trying to limit the slidedown to be triggered when the user hovers over the link within the list item. also how is the delay function that you wrote different (or better) than just adding a `delay()` to the slideup `function`

Comment: one more thing can you please explain how the closing variable works. Thanks

Comment: @mrsmee - See edited answer for new version.  The jQuery delay() queues a small delay before the next animation.  We need to be able to abort the animation if we decide to keep the menu open.  However, jQuery animations just give you stop() which is a pretty course control over the system.  We wouldn't know when calling stop() whether we were stopping the delay or stopping the slide animation without alot of work.  By writing our own delay using setTimeout, we have complete control over everything.

Comment: @mrsmee - Whenever we want to hide something, we set **closing** to the LI element and closingInterval to the value returned by setTimeout.  If the timeout expires, then the doClose method will call the slide animation on the **closing** variable and then reset it to undefined.  If we get a mouseenter event, we can check to see if **closing** is set, indicating a pending menu close.  We then either close the menu immediately (it is different than the menu we just entered), or we cancel the pending menu close (it is the same menu we just re-entered so we no longer want to close it).

Comment: wow this is really awesome!! thanks so much, where did you learn JQuery this well?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in IE7 (the sub-menu isn't hidden), got a fix for this? sorry for all the questions ;-)

Comment: @mrsmee - Not sure.  It is working in IE8 with compatability view turned on.  I'll check tomorrow from work where I have IE7.  As for learning...just using it at work alot.  You slowly learn from experience :)

Comment: @Brandon thanks alot! I actually fixed it there was a bug in my js file, so IE7 ignored the whole file.